# npm ERR! code 127. npm ERR! command failed

Tags: npm

I'm getting the following error while doing `sudo npm create svelte@latest my-app`:

```
$ sudo npm create svelte@latest my-app
npm ERR! path /home/gama
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-svelte "my-app"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-04T14_00_49_973Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't know what is breaking the install.

log:

```
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'create',
npm verb cli   'svelte@latest',
npm verb cli   'my-app',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.5.1
npm info using node@v12.22.9
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:/usr/share/nodejs/npm/npmrc Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/home/gama/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
npm timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:file:/etc/npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 13ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 13ms
npm verb logfile /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-04T14_27_35_082Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 37ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-svelte 479ms (cache miss)
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
sh: 1: create-svelte: Permission denied
npm timing command:create Completed in 570ms
npm verb stack Error: command failed
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
npm verb cwd /home/gama
npm verb Linux 5.19.0-35-generic
npm verb argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "create" "svelte@latest" "my-app" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm verb node v12.22.9
npm verb npm  v8.5.1
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /home/gama
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-svelte "my-app"
npm verb exit 127
npm timing npm Completed in 896ms
npm verb code 127

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-04T14_27_35_082Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: And what does the log say?

Comment: Updated with the log.